# Inline edit and update gridview data and saved it to the entity model database first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I have this gridview code for inline edit and update data to entity. I can edit the content inline but cannot update it. I am still not geeting the problem why it is not taking a textbox contain to the string variables. When I debug it it will show already available values from gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProductInfo" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         OnRowDeleting="grdProductInfo_RowDeleting" 
         OnRowEditing="grdProductInfo_RowEditing" 
         OnRowCancelingEdit="grdProductInfo_RowCancelingEdit" 
         OnRowDataBound="grdProductInfo_RowDataBound" 
         OnRowUpdating="grdProductInfo_RowUpdating" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="ProductID" >

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>

            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category ID" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcatId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcatId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>


            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity Per Unit" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblqpu" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuantityPerUnit") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtqpu" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuantityPerUnit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>


            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>


            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150">

            </asp:CommandField>
        </Columns>

        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

.cs code:-

```
protected void grdProductInfo_RowUpdating(object sender,   GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
         GridViewRow row = grdProductInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex];
         string pname = (row.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text;
         string catId = (row.FindControl("txtcatId") as TextBox).Text;
         string qpu = (row.FindControl("txtqpu") as TextBox).Text;
         string up = (row.FindControl("txtup") as TextBox).Text;


        using (LaunderDBEntities context = new LaunderDBEntities())
            {
                int productID = Convert.ToInt32(grdProductInfo.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
                Product obj = context.Products.First(x => x.ProductID == productID);
                obj.ProductName = pname;
                obj.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(catId);
                obj.QuantityPerUnit = Convert.ToInt32(qpu);
                obj.UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(up); 


                context.SaveChanges();

                grdProductInfo.EditIndex = -1;
                this.DataBind();
            }

    }
```

Comment: What exact problem are you facing? Are you unable to extract new values from Grid in code behind Or is the data not saving to db Or is it not refreshing in grid after successful save?

Comment: @SivaGopal its not fetching the newly entered data from grid textboxes and also not updating it to db

Answer (score 0):

Do you bind your GridView's datas in Page_Load? if yes is it in a if(!isPostback) statement ? I mean maybe it's a problem of event, if your datas are loaded before you update (like every postback), it will erase new values and then you will update with old values.